# External workspace manager plugin with declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use the mentioned plugin with a declarative pipeline, to be precise I want to convert the following documentation example to a declarative pipeline:

The pipeline code in the upstream job is the following:

```
stage ('Stage 1. Allocate workspace in the upstream job')
def extWorkspace = exwsAllocate 'diskpool1'

node ('linux') {
    exws (extWorkspace) {
        stage('Stage 2. Build in the upstream job')

        git url: 'https://github.com/alexsomai/dummy-hello-world.git'

        def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
        sh '${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean install -DskipTests'
    }
}
```

And the downstream's Pipeline code is:

```
stage ('Stage 3. Select the upstream run')
def run = selectRun 'upstream'

stage ('Stage 4. Allocate workspace in the downstream job')
def extWorkspace = exwsAllocate selectedRun: run

node ('test') {
    exws (extWorkspace) {
        stage('Stage 5. Run tests in the downstream job')

        def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
        sh '${mvnHome}/bin/mvn test'
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so how far did you get with the conversion to declarative code? You figured out the basics, right?

Comment: I already have a pretty advanced CI/CD pipeline written with a declarative syntax. Currently, im using stash/unstash to move artifacts from one node to another. Im working with android env and i need a full workspace in my tests node, what I've understood from the stash docs that its supposed to be used only for small files and we should use external workspace otherwise. Couldn't find any docs samples for this plugin with a declarative pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

I searched everywhere for a clear answer to this, yet never found a definitive answer.  So, I pulled the External Workspace Plugin code and read it.  The answer is simple as long as the plugins Model doesn't change.

Anytunc's answer is very close, but the issue is getting the path from the External Workspace Plugin and getting it into the customWorkspace configuration.

What I ended up doing was creating a method:

```
def getExternalWorkspace() {
    extWorkspace = exwsAllocate diskPoolId: "jenkins"
    return extWorkspace.getCompleteWorkspacePath()
}
```

and setting my agent to:

```
agent {
    node {
        label 'Linux'
        customWorkspace getExternalWorkspace()
    }
}
```

If you'd rather not set the entire pipeline to that path, you could create as many external workspaces as you want, then use

```
...
steps {
    dir(getExternalWorkspace()) {
        do fancy stuff
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this agent directive:

```
agent {
    node {
        label 'my-defined-label'
        customWorkspace '/some/other/path'
    }
}
```